# SQL Server 2008R2 copy database not copying security

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I'm using SSMS to copy a database from one server to another.

DatabaseName > Task > Copy...

That bit is working fine but... the source DB has usernames and various log in details so that some applications I have use SQL authentication to log in, rather than Windows authentication.

Works perfectly on the original database, but when I try to log in to the copied one, it doesn't work. It doesn't seem to be copying the security details across.

a) Is this normal, so I have to set them up again (defeats the object of copying it imho! :-) ), or

b) Am I doing something wrong?

Edit:
I took the step of deleting the copied database, removed log in from the server's security settings, recopied the database, removed the user from the database, then reset it up and it's *still* not letting me log in; even when I try to log in via SSMS using SQL authentication.

I know this is something simple, but I'm scratching my head here... :-)

Comment: a) it's normal. Backup/Restore is a much simpler and better way to do this. There is no way to extract an existing SQL authentication password so there is no way to copy a sql user over, preserving a password. You can certainly migrate a sql user but you'll have to designate a password

Answer (score 0):

Reviewing the server set up, it was only configured for Windows authentication. Once I changed to to SQL Server authentication and Windows authentication, it seems to work.